# Linking classes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, class, oop, object

I have defined a class in VBA as below

Class Employee(clsEmployee):

```
Private pEmpName As String
Private pEmpID As Long
Private pDOJ As Date
Private pManager As clsEmployee
Private pOffice As clsOffice
```

where pManager is a property of the class of type clsEmployee and pOffice is also the property of the class of type clsOffice(another class)

I also have defined the Let and Get method inside the class to read and write properties of the class as below

```
Public Property Let Name(sName As String)
    If sName <> "" Then
        pEmpName = sName
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pEmpName
End Property

Public Property Let EmployeeId(lngID As Long)
    If IsNumeric(lngID) Then
        pEmpID = lngID
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get EmployeeId() As Long
    EmployeeId = pEmpID
End Property

Public Property Let PDM(obj As clsEmployee)
    Set pPDManager = obj
End Property

Public Property Get PDM() As clsEmployee
    Set PDM = pPDManager
End Property
```

Now in the code module I have written a `test` sub to set some of the properties of my Employee class as below

```
    Sub test()
    Dim obj As clsEmployee

    Set obj = New clsEmployee

    obj.Name = "Employee 100"
    obj.EmployeeId = 11111111
    obj.PDM.Name = "Employee 1"
```

When the code executes the statement `obj.Name="Employee 100"` then the Let property which is `Name` gets executed and the pEmpName is set, while when the code tries to execute the statemnet `obj.PDM.Name="Employee 1` VBA executes the `GET method PDM`.

My question is why does the `get` method (PDM in class) gets executed on statement `obj.PDM.Name="Employee 1" when clearly I am trying to set the property instead of retrieving it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where pManager is a property of the class of type clsEmployee

Each instance of this class `clsEmployee` has to have a reference to another instance of `clsEmployee` which denotes the manager. The employee must have its manager.

The property `PDM` retuns `clsEmployee` so it needs to use `Set`

```
Public Property Set PDM(obj As clsEmployee)
    Set pManager = obj
End Property

Public Property Get PDM() As clsEmployee
    Set PDM = pManager
End Property
```

> why does the get method (PDM in class) gets executed on statement `obj.PDM.Name="Employee 1"

The employee has its manager. This manager is accessible via the property `PDM`. If we have reference to employee in variable `obj` and we want to change name of the manager of this employee, we have to get to its manager. That is why the `PDM` is called. So we get to the manager and can change its name. HTH

The test method could be now modified as following.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim mgr As clsEmployee
    Set mgr = New clsEmployee

    Dim obj As clsEmployee

    Set obj = New clsEmployee
    Set obj.PDM = mgr

    obj.Name = "Employee 100"
    obj.EmployeeId = 11111111
    obj.PDM.Name = "Employee 1"
End Sub
```

---

When we want a property which sets a reference to an object we need to use `Set-Property`. Otherwise `Let` is enough.

By convention we use `Set` for object references, like your employee. Employee is composition of data like `Name`, `Id`, `DateOfBirth` etc.
`Let` is for atomic data like `string`, `integer`, `bool` etc.

Have a look at `Worksheet` class of `Excel` library. This class has property `Name` which is of type `string`. If we have a variable which references a particular worksheet then we can change name of the worksheet like this:

```
Dim w as Worksheet
Set w = Worksheets(1)
Let w.Name = "Demo1"
```

Notice `Let` here. Because `Name` is `string-Property` `Let` is used. The keyword `Let` can be omitted though.

`Worksheet` has property `Parent` of type `Object` which is a reference to the parent of the particular workseet. If we would like to change the parent, we will write:

```
Dim w as Worksheet
Set w = Worksheets(1)
Set w.Parent = new Parent ' Is just example, it won't compile, Parent is read-only :)
```

In case when `Set` is needed it can't be omitted like `Let`.

---

In your case the properties which work with `clsEmployee` must use `Get-Set` where the properties which work with e.g. `string` use `Get-Let`.

> [Here in my
>   Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c038oor48jvg7kl/setobjectreference.JPG?dl=0)
>   I have created an very ugly picture which should illustrate the
>   situation with the object references in variables obj and mgr.

Comment: @Dee- Thanks for replying but I still have not aligned with your thoughts, can you try to explain it in a more layman way and also can you please provide some insights on when to use Set property inside a class. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @RohitSaluja I have tried to explain it, hope it not even more unclear now :).

Comment: Yes it does start to make more sense now. I just have one quick question when I did `set obj.PDM=mgr` and in the next line `obj.PDM.Name="Employee 1"` then I could see `Name` property of mgr objects also got set how did that happen?

Comment: It is correct, because it is the same object, the same memory location. The `mgr` variable references the same object as the `PDM`, that is what `Set` did, it assigned the reference of manager to `mgr` and to `PDM`. Both point to the same object. As far as the `mgr` is in scope, and the `obj` is in scope, you can access the manager using both of them.

Comment: @RohitSaluja please see edited answer. I have created a picture to illustrate the situation which might help to clarify the problem.

Comment: @Dee- Thanks a lot it helped a lot :) Appreciate the help very much !